# Importing an XML file from an email, my MySQL insert into a "text type" is adding strange characters

Tags: php, mysql, xml

I have a strange issue. My SaaS receives leads from various third party companies via email (I know ... its old school). I use the pipe to a program feature in cpanel to send the email to a script that parses out the to from subject and message. In the message is a xml message.  Here is the code for this (php):

```
$lines = explode("\n", $email_content);
 
// initialize variable which will assigned later on
$from = "";
$subject = "";
$headers = "";
$message = "";
$is_header= true;
 
//loop through each line
for ($i=0; $i < count($lines); $i++) {
if ($is_header) {
// hear information. instead of main message body, all other information are here.
$headers .= $lines[$i]."\n";
 
// Split out the subject portion
if (preg_match("/^Subject: (.*)/", $lines[$i], $matches)) {
$subject = $matches[1];
}
//Split out the sender information portion
if (preg_match("/^From: (.*)/", $lines[$i], $matches)) {
$from = $matches[1];
}
} else {
// content/main message body information
    //$message .= $lines[$i]."\n";
    $message .= $lines[$i];
}
if (trim($lines[$i])=="") {
// empty line, header section has ended
$is_header = false;
}
}
```

Then I just insert the variables into my MySQL database. For some of the emails this works perfect. But some emails the xml gets odd characters inserted. An example below

```
<?xml version=3D"1.0" encoding=3D"UTF-8"?>=0D=0A<?adf version=3D"1.0"?>==0D=0A<adf>
```

Notice the '3D' and '=0D=0A' .... I believe this may have to do with the encoding? Some are UTF 8, UTF 16 and the ones that work do not have a UTF assigned.

I am inserting the xml part into a 'TEXT' type as MySQL does not seem to have a XML option.

Comment: You see those when you view the actual source of the email in email programs. They are apparently the quoted printable representation of CLRF. I'd suggest stripping them out before you save the data.  https://askleo.com/why_does_my_email_sometimes_show_up_with_funny_characters_like_0d_in_it/ has some more information about it

Comment: _MySQL does not seem to have a XML option_ XML is text by definition

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.quoted-printable-decode.php

Comment: `=0D=0A` is probably CR LF; that is, end of line.  As for what spelled them that way, I don't know.  (I have no love for XML.)